# update a property of a row on click in swift

Tags: swift, tableview, uitableview

I have a table view which is populated with a json response from a web service. Each tableview row has an isRead property in the JSON.

If the isRead is 0, I add a small blue circle to the row like so:

```
let myActivity = self.myActivity![indexPath.row]
if let isReadCircle = cell.viewWithTag(99874) {
    if myActivity.isRead == "0" {
       println("in isread if")
       isReadCircle.layer.cornerRadius = isReadCircle.layer.frame.height/2
       isReadCircle.backgroundColor = colorWithHexString("#3399ff")
    }
}
```

When I click on a row, I want to update the isRead locally so that when the user presses back, the blueCircle is gone indicating that that row is now Read.

When I Click on the row, I update the isRead on the backend system but when I press back I do not want to have to call the web service again needlessly.

So what I tried was to update the property of the row on the fly like so:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        if let indexPath = self.myActivityTable.indexPathForSelectedRow(){
            self.myActivity?[indexPath.row].isRead = "1"

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ActivityCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
            if let isReadCircle = cell.viewWithTag(99874) {
                isReadCircle.alpha = 0
            }
        }
    }
```

I can see when I click on the row, the blue circle disappears, however when I navigate back to the table view page, the blue circle is back again. How do I the new property to persist?

Comment: you may be calling the web service again when you come back

Comment: @iRealMe I'm not calling it again when I come back because I display an activity alert when I am loading the Web service and that is not there. Also I mentioned that when I click on a row, 'I update the isRead on the backend system'. So if i was calling the web service again, it would be the correct isRead val returned. My question was wondering if i could update the property on the row locally so that i wouldn't have to re-call the WS.

Comment: Yes you can do that also. You need to reload that specific cell and then reload the tabledata.

Comment: @iRealMe So I tried adding in self.myActivityTable.reloadData() in the didSelectRowAtIndex path and I am still seeing the blue circle when I navigate back. I also tried putting self.myActivityTable.reloadData() in the viewdidAppear of the page also, same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    if let indexPath = self.myActivityTable.indexPathForSelectedRow(){
        self.myActivity?[indexPath.row].isRead = "1"

        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

        if let isReadCircle = cell.viewWithTag(99874) {
            isReadCircle.alpha = 0
        }

        tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
        tableView.reloadData()

    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

It seems that you have set segue from storyboard directly so unfortunately, the method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is not getting any chance to get fired. Move your code from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to `prepareForSegue` before performing segue. It may help!

Comment: same result as before

Comment: Please show some code of how are you setting `isRead` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method @user2363025

Comment: I have already included that code in the question. I then completely replaced that didselectrowatindexpath func for your version and got the same results. Is there something else you need to see? Can you be more specific?

Comment: @user2363025 I have updated my answer slightly. Please try it

Comment: And I actually meant where is something like `cell.isRead` but now I come to know that you did it using `cell.viewWithTag` I did not notice it

Comment: same result. I had to change the definition of cell from waht you provided however. Is that relevant? I changed it to: let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ActivityCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89686/discussion-between-irealme-and-user2363025).